# Named keys for go-sql-driver Scan()

Tags: go

When using the `go-sql-driver` it feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel a little bit. I'm used to languages where you have a data model (like a `User` class) which is strictly related to the database model. Then you can have additional models for what you want to expose on an API of course, but still, you have a model for the database object. In Go I'm not sure how to do this the best way. Below is a `GetUserByEmail` function.

```
func GetUserByEmail(email string) (*myapp.User, error) {
    smt, err := database.Prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    rows, err := smt.Query(email)
    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var users []*myapp.User

    for rows.Next() {
        var id string
        var confirmed bool
        var password string
        var email string
        var updated string
        var created string
        err = rows.Scan(&id, &confirmed, &password, &email, &updated, &created)

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        user := myapp.User{id, confirmed, created, password, email, updated}
        users = append(users, &user)
    }

    if users == nil || len(users) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("User not found.")
    }

    if len(users) != 1 {
        return nil, errors.New("Nr of users fetched: " + string(len(users)) + ". Expected: 1.")
    }

    return users[0], nil
}
```

One problem here is that if I change the order of `password` and `email` in the database, my application will silently switch those and I will get no error. That's an awful and dangerous behavior. Can `Scan()` take keys somehow or can I do this in some other way? I could of course look at `Columns()` and take the index order from there as an int (although Go doesn't seem to have that function built in) and map it to my `User` variables, but do I really need to do all that for all my database methods? Is it abstracted somewhere or do I need to do that myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One problem here is that if I change the order of password and email in the database, my application will silently switch those and I will get no error.

Arguably the best solution to this problem is simply not to use `SELECT *` -- always name your columns.  The problems with `*` can actually be larger than what you describe--what if new columns are added, which your query doesn't even need? Your code will break, for no useful reason.

But on to your larger question...

> Can `Scan()` take keys somehow or can I do this in some other way?

The standard library `sql` package does not provide this functionality. However, there are third-party libraries that do.  [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) is probably the most popular one, which is most similar to the standard library. It is my recommendation.

If you prefer [pain, suffering, and never-ending bloodshed](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/), something like [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) or [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) are also possibilities.

Comment: While you answered the question, I don't agree that doing explicit select solves the issue at all. You still have ordering in two places (one in a string and the other in arguments) and it is not obvious that these must match which could lead to dangerous bugs. I wasn't going to use an ORM for Go but after this I might have to (or write a wrapper myself to have a nice way of getting things out of the database).

Comment: By using explicit columns in your select, you have the ordering of both (the select, and the driver's interpretation of the select) defined in the same place. Yes, those could fall out of sync, but you're keeping related concerns close. This is the proper approach, in almost all cases.

Comment: As for an ORM... there's absolutely no reason to use an ORM to solve _this problem_ (personal opinion: one should never use ORMs, they invariably introduce more problems than they solve; but I know that's not a consensus opinion). `sqlx` should do everything you need.