# How to list pointers to all fields of golang struct?

Tags: go, struct

Is there a good way in golang to pass all fields of some struct instance `c`?

I'm looking for some syntactic sugar functionality, so that instead of doing this:

```
method(&c.field1, &c.field2, &c.field3, &c.field4, &c.field5, ...)
```

I could do this:

```
method(FieldsPointers(c)...)
```

I'm rather new to golang and still learning the basics, if there is no good way to do what I want for a good reason, I'd appreciate an explanation as to why.

Comment: "syntactic sugar" and Go do not mix well. Stop looking and start writing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named keys for go-sql-driver Scan()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305430/named-keys-for-go-sql-driver-scan)

Comment: I don't know what purpose downvoting without specifying a reason serves.
Does it show lack of research? Is it unclear? Or is it unhelpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides all sql specified tools, if you want to access to pointers of a struct, you can use `reflect`. Be warned that the package is tricky and rob pike said it is not for everyone.

`reflect.Value` has methods `NumField` which returns the numbber of fields in the struct and `Field(int)` which accepts the index of a field and return the field itself.

But as you want to set a value to it, it is more complicated than just calling the two methods. Let me show you in code:

```
func Scan(x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        switch f := v.Field(i); f.Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            nv := 37
            f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(nv))
        case reflect.Bool:
            nv := true
            f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(nv))
        }
    }
}
```

First, you need to pass a pointer of the struct into `Scan`, since you are modifying data and the value must be settable. That is why we are calling `.Elem()`, to dereference the pointer.

Second, `reflect.Value.Set` must use a same type to set. You cannot set `uint32` to a `int64` like normal assignment.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/grvXAc1Px8g

Comment: I won't use this solution as it is an overkill for what I'm trying to do, but this answer perfectly answers my question.